# Table with only 1 row Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I need to save company infos somewhere and I decided to make a table called entreprise_info that have only 1 company.

I want to know what is the best practice in this situation.

The table that I created:

```
class CreateEnterpriseInfosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('enterprise_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->string('street_address', 50);
            $table->string('postal_address', 50);
            $table->string('phone', 17);
            $table->string('fax', 17);
            $table->string('logo_path', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('enterprise_infos');
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same situation and I did it like you did.

Comment: You need to explain more... are you going to store more than 1 companies or is it just for 1 company and that's it ?

Comment: It's only 1 company and that's it

Comment: Then, it depends how are you going to use it, are you going to edit that data ? Is it going to be constant ? If it is going to be constant, then create a new `config` file and put it under that folder, so you can use it like `config('company.name')` or `config('phone')`, etc. Also doing this you can cache it so no need to read it from file all the time.

Comment: I am going to edit that data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario I will go for two columns in table

Table Name :`enterprise_infos`

columns Name : `setting_key| setting_value`

key column contain `street_address,postal_address,phone,faxlogo_path`

This type of schema avoid you to create new columns whenever new setting_key is introduced

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `enterprise_infos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `setting_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `setting_value` longtext DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `enterprise_infos` (`id`, `setting_key`, `setting_value`) VALUES
(1, 'name', NULL),
(2, 'street_address', NULL),
(3, 'postal_address', NULL),
(4, 'phone', NULL),
(5, 'fax', NULL),
(6, 'logo_path', NULL);
```

[image]